# Website querys advanced

Tags: php, mysql

I am building website like social network.

And i made 3 tables:  `users`, `posts`, and `friends`.

How can I write code to display posts from me and from my friends:
`Users: id, email, username, password, image`

`Posts: id, pid, pname, ppost, pimage`

`Friends: id, user1, user2, friends(yes or no)`

So i need to check if user1 is $_SESSION[user] , than too check every row with friends as yes and than echo every post from user1(me) and other users who are friend of mine.

I made some code but it echo posts only from me and first user i marked as friend, i can't show posts from other users i marked as friend.

Users: id:1 email:email@email.com, username:test, password:xd , image:This is link

Users: id:2 , email: test@email.com, username:test2, password:xd, image:Link

Users: id:3 , email: test2@email.com, username:test3, password:xd, image:Link

Posts: id:1 , pid(this is publisher id):etc 1,2,3 , pname:Name of publisher , ppost:Text , pimage: image of publisher:

So just imagine i have 3 posts from 3 diferent users

Friends: id:(auto)1,2,3,4 , user1(user1 is session user) if i login to first user it will be 1, user2(id of other user like 2(test2)), friends(yes)

Friends: id:(auto)1,2,3,4 , user1(user1 is session user) if i login to first user it will be 1, user2(id of other user like 3(test3)), friends(yes)

So i need to echo posts from users(me) , and two others and every other user which have friends(yes) , and don't show posts from users which are marked no.

I made this so far: Querys:

```
 `session_start();
$res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=".$_SESSION['user']);
 $row=mysql_fetch_array($res);
$res2=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE pid=".$_SESSION['user']);
$row2=mysql_fetch_array($res2);

$res3=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM obavijesti");
 $row3=mysql_fetch_array($res3);

$res5=mysql_query("SELECT user1, user2 FROM osobe WHERE friends='yes' AND user1='$_SESSION[user]' order by id limit 5000");

 $row5=mysql_fetch_array($res5);
$user2=$row5['user2'];
$user1=$_SESSION['user'];

`
```

PHP script:

```
<?php $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE pid='$user1' OR pid='$user2' order by id desc limit 5000") ?>
```

```html
<div class="publishcontent">
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="testt.css">
<div class="posts"> 
  <article class="post">
    <header class="post-header"><span class="post-user-name"><?php echo $row4['pname']; ?></span><span class="post-header-posted">Objavljeno: Danas</span></header>
    <div class="post-flex-container">
      <aside class="post-user">
        <image src="<?php echo $row4['pimage']; ?>" class="post-user-image"></image>
        <div class="post-user-status is-online">TEST</div>
        <div class="post-user-posts">Broj objava: x</div>
        <div class="post-user-joined"><?php if($row['spol'] == "zensko" ) {

          echo "Pridružila se";

          }
          else {
echo "Pridružio se";
            } ?> : <?php echo $row['date']; ?></div>
      </aside>
      <section class="post-content">
  
   
        <p>

        <?php echo htmlspecialchars($row4['ppost']); ?>
  </p>
      </section>
    </div>

  </article>

</div>

</div>
```

```
<?php endwhile ?>
```

And it only displays posts from me and first person i marked as friend, but don't show posts from third person

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

I would go back to your mysql and refactor your database schema. Your Users table will need to have a one to many relationship with user_id in your Friends table. And your Users table will also need to have a one to many relationship with friend_id in the Friends table. (this allows you to store the user_id of the friend and the user_id of the befriended.) The users table will also have a one to many relationship with the Posts table. Then Change Your mysql to use an inner join query. The inner join query will allow you to query all the results from each table with one query. Here is a link to learn more about that. http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp

```
SELECT users.*, friends.*, posts.* FROM users INNER JOIN friends ON users.id = friends.user_id INNER JOIN posts ON users.id = posts.user_id
```

Also you can add a WHERE clause at the end of the query to get related posts and friends for the current logged in user

Comment: But my users table is like this:
id , user1 , user2, friends
1, 1, 2 , yes
2, 1,3 , yes
3, 2,3 ,yes
if u mean what i want , i didn't learn inner join yet , if u could send me some link , and what do you mean many to many relationships . And do you know how could i check if user1 is friend with user2 and user3, (User1=1, User2=2 user3=3, bcs they are id's from users table) , with that code above it only displays posts from user1(me)(bcs i am logged in) and user2 , but not user3

Comment: I revised my answer to help you out

Comment: Thank You , i will try it :)

Comment: Can you give my answer a vote and click the checkbox next to it if you feel that i was able to answer your question. Thanks

Comment: Sure , you will only need to wait my 15 rep so everyone can see :)

Comment: I did everything u asked, but i don't know can i do that inner join , can u write it for me and explain , i am looking on w3school and youtube how to do it but i don't understand. Thank You
`<?php $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE pid='$_SESSION[user]' INNER JOIN friends ON Customers.CustomerID=Orders.CustomerID order by id desc limit 5000") ?>`  After INNER JOIN friends ON ,  i don't know what to write

Comment: Yup. I will post it a little later. I'm going to be away from my computer for a bit.

Comment: `<?php $result = mysql_query("SELECT osobe.user_id, osobe.friend_id, posts.* FROM posts INNER JOIN osobe ON posts.pid='$_SESSION[user]' OR posts.pid=osobe.friend_id WHERE osobe.user_id='$_SESSION[user]'  order by id desc limit 5000") ?>`
OK i did some research, and now it displays how i want, but when i am logged in as user1 it will display data twice from user 1, and once from other users if they are my friend, when i login to user2 it will display once posts from user1, and twice from user2. I figure it out, it displays twice cuz i have same user_id twice in "osobe". See next comment-sry

Comment: It's all good. Glad you figured it out. Let me know if you have any more questions.

Comment: I reedit my code now  `<?php $result = mysql_query("SELECT posts.* FROM posts INNER JOIN osobe ON posts.pid=osobe.friend_id WHERE osobe.user_id='$_SESSION[user]' order by id desc limit 5000") ?>`
It only displays posts from my friends, not my posts, do u know why?
And i should get some break and relax, but i just learned something new and i can't stop it :D

Comment: Revised my answer to help you out some more. You might need to customize it some for your liking.

Comment: Thanks :)  thats all i got for now until next problem hehe